# Converting nested for loops with JAVA8 filter

Tags: java-8

```
class MyObject {
  String key;
  String value;
}
```

I have two lists, `listA` and `listB` containing `MyObject` objects.

I'm trying to convert the below nested for loops to Java8 streams based :

```
for(String objA : listA) {
   for(String objB : listB) {
       if(objA.getKey().equals(objB.getKey()) && !objA.getValue().equals(objB.getValue())) {
           // create an object of a different class `MyDiff` with params as 
           // objA.getKey(), objA.getValue(), objB.getValue()
           // and push it to a list.
       }
   }
}
```

I tried to solve this with JAVA8 as,

```
List<MyDiff> diff = listA.streams().filter(objA -> {
    listB.stream.anyMatch(objB -> objA.getKey().equals(obj.getKey()) && !objA.getValue().equals(obj.getValue()))
})
```

But `anyMatch` doesn't return an object and I can't use `filter` instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flatMap()` and `filter()` operator to complete.

```
List<MyDiff> diff = 
    listA.stream().flatMap(objA ->
        listB.stream()
             .filter(objB -> objA.getKey().equals(objB.getKey()) && !objA.getValue().equals(objB.getValue()))
             .map(objB -> new MyDiff(objA.getKey(), objA.getValue(), objB.getValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```